# How do I distinguish jQuery selector strings from other strings

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to check the 'type' of a string. Particularly, how do I distinguish jQuery selector strings from other strings? In other words, how should selectorTest be implemented in the following code?

```
    var stringType = function( value ) {   
        var htmlExpr = /^[^<]*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*$/;

        if ( htmlExpr.test(value) ) {
            return "htmlstring";
        }
        if ( selectorTest ) {
            return "selectorstring";  
        }
        return "string";
    }
```

Comment: You can't. jQuery selectors can be pretty much anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [do what jQuery does](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L104) internally and check if it's HTML or not with [the following regex](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L20):

```
/^(?:[^<]*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*$|#([\w\-]+)$)/
```

e.g.:

```
var stringType = function( value ) {   
    var htmlExpr = /^(?:[^<]*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*$|#([\w\-]+)$)/;

    if ( htmlExpr.test(value) ) {
        return "htmlstring";
    }
    if ( selectorTest ) {
        return "selectorstring";  
    }
    return "string";
}
```

---

Note that in more recent versions of jQuery, [there's another check](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L99) explicitly for "starting with `<`" and "ending with `>`" to skip the regex (purely for speed).  [The check looks like this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L99) in core (as of jQuery 1.6.1):

```
if ( typeof selector === "string" ) {
    // Are we dealing with HTML string or an ID?
    if ( selector.charAt(0) === "<" && selector.charAt( selector.length - 1 ) === ">" && selector.length >= 3 ) {
        // Assume that strings that start and end with <> are HTML and skip the regex check
        match = [ null, selector, null ];
    } else {
        match = quickExpr.exec( selector );
    }
```

Comment: You did not exactly answer my question, but I decided to do what you suggested anyway. That is, Im simply saying that a string is a selector string, if it is not an html string. 

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, wrong. The regular expression you provided matches both HTML and selectors that contain IDs only. When the second group (`|#(\w\-]+)$)`) is matched, [string is assumed to be an ID-only selector](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L110). I'm not sure, maybe it's done for performance, but the real regular expression to test if the string is HTML would be `/^\s*[^<]*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*\s*$/`.

Answer (score -2):

maybe `($(value).size()>0`) ?

It will test if the selector is recognized.

But in my opinion, it is a bit strange way to do...

Comment: absolutely false if your string contains invalid chars (will throw exception).