# String is html or selector? javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string, selector

I took some code from here: - [How do I distinguish jQuery selector strings from other strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007821/how-do-i-distinguish-jquery-selector-strings-from-other-strings) - and modified it a bit. However, I CANNOT get the match to work correctly. I've tried both `.test` and `.exec`.

```
var htmlExpr = /^(?:[^<]*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*$|#([\w\-]+)$)/;
if ( selector.charAt(0) === "<" && selector.charAt( selector.length - 1 ) === ">" && selector.length >= 3 || htmlExpr.test( selector )) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

I'm using `#mydiv` and `<div class='gallery'>gallery</div>blah` as `selector`

Both return true.

What's going on here that I'm missing?

Comment: **Why** are you trying this ? I'm not sure this would even be possible with a regex and I cannot see any possible use. Note that the answer you're using is about testing if a string is HTML, which is the opposite of what you write here.

Comment: In your `if` statement, why are you using both methods? In the SO question you provided, the answer says to **either** use regex **or** the `charAt` & `length` method. Why bother appending `htmlExpr.test( selector )` at the end?

Comment: @dystroy jQuery uses it for determining if the string you've passed in as the initial parameter is a selector or a string. There's is somewhat more complex, I have a simple use case in a small internal library update where this is necessary.

Comment: @Ian javascript *SHOULD* execute the contents as soon as a match is made. IE, the second evaluation (after the `||`) is ignored if the first is true. The SO question is returning two different values depending on which evaluation is successful. I don't care which is successful here, only that one *is*.

Comment: @RandyHall which of your both selector is supposed not to return true?

Comment: I understand, but my point is that both aren't necessary. The answer basically says "Here, use this regex", which should work. Then, they also say "But you could use the newer version to check if it's technically a valid HTML element in the string instead". So either should work fine. You should be testing just the regex to see what the problem is, because I can get it to work without it.

Comment: @Nelson `#mydiv` shouldn't. It should return true for any string containing an html element.

Comment: The problem is with the regex, whatever the specific problem is.

Comment: @Ian The "first" evaluation is a shortcut, it assumes that any string starting with `<` and ending with `>` is html. Since html could be a mix of elements and text nodes, this isn't always the case. So the first evaluation is faster, and if it is true, will return true. The regex is to check if an HTML string exists anywhere in `selector`

Comment: @Ian perhaps, but this is the copy-paste regex that jQuery uses to examine strings passed to it. jQuery is typically pretty good at catching massive errors that would destroy the entire library, which is why I feel something else must be wrong.

Comment: I believe in the latest jQuery they've simplified the rule of selector vs HTML to basically be "if begins with < then HTML, else selector" because of the number of bugs around this

Comment: @RandyHall I know jQuery wouldn't miss this. But I also wouldn't base my code off of something that simple. You really think that little regex will fully validate the string? If you look at the jQuery source that the link's answer points to, jQuery does a lot more with the result of the regex...not just return true/false based on its result.

Comment: Starting here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L111 jQuery begins processing the result of the regex match. Not just return true/false

Comment: @Ian Righto, but I don't need it to do all those things. I need it to do a basic check on a string. I need it to be lightweight with only a minimal flexibility. It doesn't have to fully validate, it just has to *get close*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#mydiv` is returning true as you've specifically check for it in the regex in this part `|#([\w\-]+)$` , you should eliminate that part so `#mydiv` doesn't match, like this:

```js
function isHtml(selector) {
    var htmlExpr = /^[^<]*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*$/;
    if ( selector.charAt(0) === "<" && selector.charAt( selector.length - 1 ) === ">" && selector.length >= 3 || htmlExpr.test( selector )) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
} 

// Demo
console.log(isHtml("#mydiv")); // false
console.log(isHtml("<div class='gallery'>gallery</div>blah")); // true
```

Comment: /^(?:[^<]*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*$|([\w\-]+)$)/ seems to work, at least for both of these cases! good catch (I'm TERRIBLE at regex).